# Is there a better way to do this? Counting Files, and directories via for loop vs map

Tags: python, python-3.x

Folks,

I'm trying to optimize this to help speed up the process...

What I am doing is creating a dictionary of scandir entries...
e.g.

```
fs_data = {}
for item in Path(fqpn).iterdir():
    # snipped out a bunch of normalization code
    fs_data[item.name.title().strip()] = item

{'file1': <file1 scandisk data>, etc}
```

and then later using a function to gather the count of files, and directories in the data.

Now I suspect that the new code, using map could be optimized to be faster than the old code.  I suspect that having to run the list comprehension twice, once for files, and once for directories.

But I can't think of a way to optimize it to only have to run once.

Can anyone suggest a way to sum the files, and directories at the same time in the new version?  (I could fall back to the old code, if necessary)

But I might be over optimizing at this point?

Any feedback would be welcome.

```
def new_fs_counts(fs_entries) -> (int, int):
    """
    Quickly count the files vs directories in a list of scandir entries
    Used primary by sync_database_disk to count a path's files & directories

    Parameters
    ----------
    fs_entries (list) - list of scandir entries

    Returns
    -------
    tuple - (# of files, # of dirs)

    """
    def counter(fs_entry):
        return (fs_entry.is_file(), not fs_entry.is_file())

    mapdata = list(map(counter, fs_entries.values()))
    files = sum(files for files, _ in mapdata)
    dirs = sum(dirs for _, dirs in mapdata)
    return (files, dirs)
```

vs

```
def old_fs_counts(fs_entries) -> (int, int):
    """
    Quickly count the files vs directories in a list of scandir entries
    Used primary by sync_database_disk to count a path's files & directories

    Parameters
    ----------
    fs_entries (list) - list of scandir entries

    Returns
    -------
    tuple - (# of files, # of dirs)

    """
    files = 0
    dirs = 0
    for fs_item in fs_entries:
        is_file = fs_entries[fs_item].is_file()
        files += is_file
        dirs += not is_file
    return (files, dirs)
```

Comment: i don't understand what you are doing in the preprocessing?  what is `['file1': <file1 scandisk data>, etc]`  a dictionary or a list?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get typing this up at 2am.
It's a dictionary that contains the directory entries.  The primary key is the filename of each file.

Why?  So that I don't have to keep hitting the file system while I am generating the database entries.

Comment: and so you are just looking for a fast way to iterate through a dictonary ang get the number of files and folders it contains?

Comment: Try using `glob`.

Comment: I already am, for gathering the data.  This is part of a gallery application, so I am doing quite a bit of file system work periodically.

So I am using Pathlib, glob from path lib for gathering the data, which goes into the list of dictionary entries, and then is either added to the database, or compared for updating.

There is one section where I need to generate the file/dir count, so that code needs to be tight as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` *is* fast here if you map the `is_file` function directly:

```
files = sum(map(os.DirEntry.is_file, fs_entries.values()))
dirs = len(fs_entries) - files
```

(Something with `filter` might be even faster, at least if most entries *aren't* files. Or `filter` with `is_dir` if that works for you and most entries aren't directories. Or `itertools.filterfalse` with `is_file`. Or using `itertools.compress`. Also, *counting* `True` with `list.count` or `operator.countOf` instead of *summing* bools might be faster. But all of these ideas take more code (and some also memory). I'd prefer my above way.)

Comment: That's strange. I would have thought that the cached reference in scandir would have nullified any speed benefit.

Comment: That's strange. I would have thought that the cached reference in scandir would have nullified any speed benefit.

But timeit, is certainly showing a significant speed up.

New :  0.14651616697665304,
old :  0.08255887508857995,
kelly :  0.014771000016480684

I'll have to revisit this...  Thank you for the suggestion.  It's about 4-5 times faster than the original version...  And about 10-11 times faster than the optimized map version that was suggested earlier.

Comment: Quick timing testing does show files = sum(map(os.DirEntry.is_file, fs_entries.values())), is the fastest. Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminSchollnick Nice. Even faster than in my own timing. I don't know about the caching, but the previous `map` solutions at least had the overhead of calling the additional function and fetching the method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, map is definitely **not the right answer here.**

This morning I got up and created a test using timeit...
and it was a bit of a splash of reality to the face.

Without optimizations, new vs old, the new map code was roughly 2x the time.

New :  0.023185124970041215
old :  0.011841499945148826

I really ended up falling for a bit of click bait, and thought that rewriting with MAP would gain some better efficiency.

For the sake of completeness.

```
from timeit import timeit
import os


new = '''
def counter(fs_entry):
    files = fs_entry.is_file()

    return (files, not files)

mapdata = list(map(counter, fs_entries.values()))
files = sum(files for files, _ in mapdata)
dirs = sum(dirs for _, dirs in mapdata)
#dirs = len(fs_entries)-files
'''
#dirs = sum(dirs for _, dirs in mapdata)

old = '''
files = 0
dirs = 0
for fs_item in fs_entries:
   is_file = fs_entries[fs_item].is_file()
   files += is_file
   dirs += not is_file
'''

fs_location = '/Volumes/4TB_Drive/gallery/albums/collection1'
fs_data = {}
for item in os.scandir(fs_location):
    fs_data[item.name] = item

print("New : ", timeit(stmt=new, number=1000, globals={'fs_entries':fs_data}))
print("old : ", timeit(stmt=old, number=1000, globals={'fs_entries':fs_data}))
```

And while I was able close the gap with some **optimizations**.. (Thank you Lee for your suggestion)

New :  0.10864979098550975
old :  0.08246175001841038

It is clear that the for loop solution is easier to read, faster, and just simpler.

The speed difference between new and old, doesn't seem to be map specifically.

The duplicate sum statement added .021, and The biggest slow down was from the second fs_entry.is_file, it added .06x to the timings...

Comment: Can you rerun with my solution included?

Comment: Also, what/where is the click bait you're referring to?